# Index is Out of Bounds for Axis 0 with Size 0

Tags: python, numpy, for-loop

I am trying to subset a particular list based on the cummulative sum of its value attaining a particular threshold(percent). I tried out For Loops and List Comprehension but I get this Out of Bounds error. Can an experienced hands help see where I went wrong.

```
def selection(value1, percent):
    for i in range(len(value1)):
        cum_sum =  np.cumsum(value1[:i])[-1]        
        if (cum_sum * 0.01 - percent) < 1e-6:
            y = value1[:i]
                
return y
```

With comprehension list:

```
def selection(value1, percent):

    y = [value1[:i] for i in range(len(value1)) if np.cumsum(value1[:i])[-1]*0.01 - percent < 1e-6]
                
return y
```

Convereted the list to an np.array but still obtained error. A kind help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### First, to answer your question of where you went wrong:

In the first iteration of your for loop, the value of `i` is `0` (recall that python is zero indexed). As a result, when you pass `value1[:i]` to `cumsum`, you are actually passing an empty array (try `print(np.arange(5)[:0])`). This is because the syntax `[:i]` selects the entries up to *but not including* index `i`. The error then arises when you try to take the last element of the list (via `[-1]`)

This is the same problem that comes up in your list comprehension version (since it's essentially the same loop.)

#### A solution

Below is a minimal solution that illustrates how you can use `where` to quickly solve this problem while only having to call `cumsum` once. (Note that in your example, it is called in every iteration of the loop!)

```
import numpy as np

values = np.random.rand(20)
values = np.sort(values)

percent = 0.5

target_index = np.where( np.cumsum(values) >= np.sum(values) * percent )[0][0]

subset_values = values[:target_index]

print(target_index)
```

Comment: Your explanations are quite clear and succinct. Now I understand how best to handle such for loops. Gracias!